# How to configure snapper for home (restore snapper config)

Tags: btrfs, snapper

I've configured my openSuse installation to have /home partition formatted with btrfs and added snapper config for it (with timeline, I guess).

It was a bad idea, I know, but I was inspired by the btrfs and was willing to try it out as part of backuping strategy even for home partition (snapper + snapsync + external usb drive with btrfs).

So I had to add some subvolumes (for VMs and for .cache), but even that was not enouph.
I didn't want to lose time reconfiguring the system and simply turned off snapper (possibly by deleting snapper config somehow.

Now I have a couple of snapper snapshots for home and don't know how to clean them up.
I would like to use Yast-snapper to review the existing snapshots in a user-friendly way. But I'm missing snapper configuration.

```
# snapper -c home create-config /home
creating btrfs subvolume .snapshots failed since it already exists.
```

Possibly I could create snapper config manually (by coping and editing one for root and adding it to /etc/sysconfig/snapper, for example).

My issue is: I don't want to configure all the subvolumes for all of the existing users and don't want my home to run out of space (it's on a separate partition, so root partition is not in danger).

But I would like to use snapper to backup home partition also (I'm only using home to store user configurations - the documents/pictures/videos are stored on separate partition, symlinked from user-dir)...

TLDR:
Does it make sense to backup home (if it contains no documents)? (haven't used backups till now)
How to restore snapper config?
Which subvolumes to create for each user under home?
How to create skeleton with subvolumes for some dirs?

Comment: Did you find answer for your questions?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've left the issues to the time where I'm not so busy to try things out.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Snapper#Creating_a_new_configuration) or on [openSUSE github](https://github.com/openSUSE/snapper/issues/369).

Briefly, it's 3 steps:

1. create a subvolume .snapshots manually
2. edit `SNAPPER_CONFIGS=""` in the config file (`/etc/default/snapper or /etc/conf.d/snapper`).
3. create your volume config such as `/etc/snapper/configs/home`.

I also had to `reboot / restart` snapper for changes to take effect.